# restore saved / initial value for select2 4.0.3 with rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, coffeescript, jquery-select2

I'm using select2 version 4.0.3

below is my html using select tag rails helper

```
<%= f.select(:hotel_id, [], {},  :class => 'select2-autocomplete' ) %>
```

below is my coffeescript (working for create new)

```
  $('.select2-autocomplete').select2
  multiple: false
  width: "98%"
  placeholder: "Type Hotel name"
  minimumInputLength: 3
  ajax:
    url: '/hotels/search_name.json'
    dataType: 'json'
    delay: 250
    data: (params) ->
      q: params.term
    processResults: (data, params) ->
      results: $.map data, (item)->
        id: item.id
        text: item.name
```

previously it done using initSelection for select2 version 3.5.3 but then there is changes for version 4.0.3, and I did read the [documentation](http://select2.github.io/options.html#ajax) but still has no good result,

my problem is when user edit page, I need to restore previous select value and show it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally after some trial and error below how to use select2 version 4 to restore the value, it's probably not clean but it works

```
<% if f.object.persisted? && f.object.hotel_id  %>
  <% if f.object.hotel_id > 0 %>
    <% value = f.object.hotel_id  %>
    <% text  = Hotel.find(value).name %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
<%= f.select(:hotel_id, options_for_select([["#{text}", value.to_s]]),  {selected: value},  :class => 'select2-autocomplete' ) %>
```

The key answer is bottom line,

- using f.select,
- generate option using option_for_select
- make sure the option is using string value.to_s
- under option use { selected: value}

hope it can help other rails users that using select2 with ajax search